# Show validity of Logic formula

Tags: logic, proof-verification

> Show that a formula $$ is a valid formula if and only if the formula $(∀ )$ is a valid
>   formula.

Consider the direction:

**(1)** Assume $$ is valid, we have to show $(\forall x )$ is valid. It follows from definition, $\emptyset \vDash $. How do I show $\emptyset \vDash (\forall x )$ from this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\emptyset \not \models \forall x \phi$. Then there is a model $\mathcal M$ such that $\mathcal M \models \neg \forall x \phi$. Hence there is some $x \in \lfloor \mathcal M \rfloor$ such that 
$$
\mathcal M \models \neg \phi[x].
$$

This witnesses that $\emptyset \not \models \phi$. Contradiction!